# Is there a way to write scripts in RSA Archer so Archer can call an API to trigger other web applications?

Tags: rsa-archer-grc

I am trying to trigger a function developed in a web application when a record in RSA Archer is updated, for example Control Procedure records. But we are not allowed to call API outside RSA Archer (such as Python PyPl)

Does RSA Archer have a function or place where I can write some custom scripts and execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use a custom object within the application and use JavaScript to make the API calls.

Comment: Thank you for your reply DjP, I used Custom Object in Archer to call an API, but I want to trigger the API call when a scheduler changes the field value (i.e capture the change using jQuery change() function), but I found the field value is updated inside  Archer instead of going through front-end, therefore my jQuery function won't work. Do you have any suggestions on this please? Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way of achieving this within Archer.  As you scene Custom Objects only fire when the user is in the record and not via a batch, data feed/import or Archer APIs.  You'd have to build an external application utilizing Archers APIs (web services/REST) that process the data, call your APIs if needed and update the records in Archer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply DjP